# PHP Server to Server Transfers

Tags: php

We are storing a Final Image, Back and Front proof and a thumbnail on one server, but what I need to is when the user goes to took at their images, it needs to transfer the image from the image server on to our web server.

I have tried opening the the server connection and the transferring the image from where it is to where the .php file that has opened the connection is, but i just continually got errors saying that the stream could not be opened because the directory didn't exist.
And i had tried to open up two connections (one for each server) and using get and put to move it from server to server.

These images can't be stored on a intermittent PC.
Any help or advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try transferring the image directly to the user through [Apache mod-proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) connection. I'm sure there are ways to work out user permissions between the servers.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the image server you're using?  Are you sure you need to transfer the image across to your other server rather than just having the HTML the web server is producing link to the image server?

Other than that you might want to look into using NFS rather than programatically transferring the files yourself every time they're requested (assuming you're using some form of *nix on both machines and can create NFS shares).

Comment: Well i was thinking about doing that, but i am relatively new to PHP coding and even HTML (the shame), but i have to do some processing of the images to figure out what images need to be displayed.
and i didn't think i could process a whole folder on another server without being on that server.

Comment: Sorry,the image server is where a program users use (in browser) create their own business cards, and it fixes the bleeds etc. Then it is saved on that server, unfortunately my boss told them we would give them a dedicated server, otherwise i would have had them stored on our regular one.

Comment: In that case you could use NFS to copy the files from one server to the other once the user's happy with their cards, NFS just mounts as a directory so it's as easy as copying files between local directories.

If you want to go the less clean POSTing with PHP route take a look at using curl.